# Do something if url is exact match in php

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I want to run some code if there is an exact url match.

I currently have this:

```
//Returns 'https://www.someurl.com'
$browserUrl  = curPageURL();
```

Now I have one line that is meant to build a new url based on `$browserUrl`. For that I have created this:

```
<?php
   //Gets the url of a specific page
   $page = icl_object_id(2880, 'page', true);
   $url = get_permalink($page);
   //Cplits the url into useful parts for rebuilding
   $parts = explode("/", $url);
?>

//Here I am rebuilding the url based on the url I retrieved with the code above
<a href="<?php echo curPageURL() . $parts[4] . '#sendMessage'; ?>"><?php _e('Send us an Email','optionsBlock'); ?></a>
```

But, by using a ternary operator, what I am actually trying to do is this:

```
<a href="<?php echo curPageURL() . $browserUrl == 'https://www.someurl.com' ? $parts[3] : $parts[4] . '#sendMessage'; ?>"><?php _e('Send us an Email','optionsBlock'); ?></a>
```

But this is not working as expected because it is not picking up direct url match. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to use `$parts[3]` or `$parts[4]` depending on the `$browserUrl` check, and the ternary operator is the problem, then I suggest to make a new variable, let's say `$part`, holding the result of the ternary operator, then use it in the concatenation, like this:

```
<?php
   //Gets the url of a specific page
   $page = icl_object_id(2880, 'page', true);
   $url = get_permalink($page);
   //Cplits the url into useful parts for rebuilding
   $parts = explode("/", $url);
   $part = $browserUrl == 'https://www.someurl.com' ? $parts[3] : $parts[4];
?>

//Here I am rebuilding the url based on the url I retrieved with the code above
<a href="<?php echo curPageURL() . "{$part}#sendMessage"; ?>"><?php _e('Send us an Email','optionsBlock'); ?></a>
```

Or you can use the ternary operator inside the concatenation, but you need to enclose it in brackets to work properly, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo curPageURL() . ($browserUrl == 'https://www.someurl.com' ? $parts[3] : $parts[4]) . '#sendMessage'; ?>"><?php _e('Send us an Email','optionsBlock'); ?></a>
```

Personally I don't like this, as it's somewhat confusing to read.